# Uploading file via Paramiko SFTP not working

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko

I am using the below Python code to upload a file via SFTP using Paramiko. The connection "seems" to be fine, the code executes to the end, just the file isn't reaching the destination when I check in FileZilla.

I have checked and set permissions on the file to 777 (just to be sure). I have also checked my file path string in a separate terminal and the path is valid.

```
import paramiko
.
.

transport = paramiko.Transport((host, port))
transport.connect(username = username, password = password)
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)

sftp.put(filePath, "/")  # Upload file to root FTP folder
sftp.close()
transport.close()
```

What can I do to debug this? Anything I can print out, check connection succeeded etc?

Answer (score 14):

The second argument of [`SFTPClient.put`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.put) (`remotepath`)  is path to a **file**, not a folder:

> the destination path on the SFTP server. Note that the filename should be included. Only specifying a directory may result in an error.

Try this:

```
sftp.put(filePath, "/filename")
```